# How do I bind a TextBlock to an internal field using XAML?

Tags: c#, xaml, binding

I have a base DataClass that contains date information as a string.

```
public class DataClass
{
    string DateInfo;
}
```

I have a UserControl which contains an instance of that class, and a TextBlock.

```
public partial class MyControl : UserControl
{
    public DateInfo MyData = new DateInfo();
}
```

In the XAML, I'm trying to bind MyControl's TextBlock to the control's own internal instance of DataClass, but I'm having difficulty in establishing the path. I tried *RelativeSource Self*, but that only refers to the TextBlock itself. So then I tried this

```
<TextBlock x:Name="DateCreated"
Text="{Binding Path=MyData.Created, 
Converter={StaticResource dateConverter},
RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}" />
```

But I'm getting the error "BindingExpression path error: 'MyData' proeperty not found on object." The compiler won't let me set the AncestorType to MyControl; it insists that I use the generic type name.

What am I missing?